# How to correct for inter-eye correlation in Cox survival analysis where the event but not the independent factor is eye-specific?

Tags: survival, cox-model

Good morning,

I have two groups of patients (treated / untreated) and I want to compute (in R) the hazard ratio of using the treatment on the occurence of an event.
The event is an eye pathology relapse that can occur in one or both eyes of the patient.
The treatment is systemic (not eye-specific).

1. Is it correct to use the 'cluster' term to correct for inter-eye correlation in Cox survival analysis?

I used the coxph function and specified the cluster term "cluster = 'code'" where code refers to the patient (so there is 2 lines with the same 'code', one for the right eye and one for the left eye).

I am surprised to find that the SE is smaller when I used the cluster term as compared to when I do not specify it (see output below):

without cluster:
[image: without cluster]

with cluster:
[image: with cluster]

2. I should report the "Robust" output, shouldn't I?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using robust cluster variance to handle pairing of eyes within individuals has been accepted practice for over 30 years. See Section 8.4.2 of the 2000 book [Modeling Survival Data](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842) by Therneau and Grambsch, which in turn refers to studies dating back to 1989 on diabetic retinopathy.

Inference should be based on the robust estimate, although you might want to report both error estimates. The difference between the 2 error estimates should be relatively small, as they are here, unless you are omitting some important outcome-associated predictor from the model. Differences can go either way; the Therneau and Grambsch example has 2 Cox regression coefficients, one with a higher and one with a lower nominal SE for the clustered estimate.

With respect to your particular data, you seem to have 50% missing data, and only 10 events. Those issues raise questions about the generalizability of the results. [Multiple imputation](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/) would seem to be important here.